# Why is not get_post_meta working?

Tags: wordpress

i am using following get_post_meta function but it is not showing any values, it is showing blank result

```
$meta_values = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'salary', true );
```

I am able to see the value present in phpmyadmin .I am using it in a **plugin** in **action(save_post,sftoproject)**, but it is showing any value in my code.

Here's my code

```
add_action('save_post','user_sf_project');
function user_sf_project($post_id){
$SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP/soapclient/';
require_once ($SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforcePartnerClient.php');
require_once ($SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforceHeaderOptions.php');
require_once ('Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP/Samples/userAuth.php');

try {
  $mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
  $mySoapClient =  $mySforceConnection->createConnection($SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/partner.wsdl.xml');
  $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login("username", "password");

  $postdata = get_post($post_id);
  $meta_values = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'salary', true );
  $fields = array (
    'Name' => $post_id,
    'First_Name__c' => $postdata->post_title,
    'Salary__c' => $meta_values,
  );

  $sObject = new SObject();
  $sObject->fields = $fields;
  $sObject->type = 'NewObject__c';

  $createResponse = $mySforceConnection->create(array($sObject));

  print_r($createResponse);

  $ids = array();
  foreach ($createResponse as $createResult) {
    print_r($createResult);
    array_push($ids, $createResult->id);
  }

} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $mySforceConnection->getLastRequest();
echo $e->faultstring;
}
```

Comment: Did you check that you set a valid $post_id ? (it could be unaccessible if it's not a global variable)

Comment: Also could you please let us know if the content type you are trying to access is custom or not? From the docs: It is a wrapper for get_metadata('post'). To return all of the custom fields, see get_post_custom().

Comment: i checked it and it is correct. i am getting result for get_post($post_id) but not for get_post_meta( $post_id, 'salary', true )

Comment: yes it is custom type

Comment: Not working, because it's the expected behaviour, explained in the docs :-) (added the answer, it could be helpful to other people, so it would be good to adjust the question title to include "for custom type")

Comment: i dont understand that u said, can u explain about it

Comment: Edited my answer and added an example! Hope it't more clear now (sorry for my poor English)

Answer (score 0):

From the [WP docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta):

> It is a wrapper for get_metadata('post'). To return all of the custom
>   fields, see get_post_custom().

You must use get_post_custom() function (not get_post_meta) for custom post types, but I highly recommend that you always use **[get_metadata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_metadata)** instead of get_post_meta() and get_post_custom() to avoid simple problems...

Example for get_metadata():

```
get_metadata('your_custom_post_type', $post_id, 'salary', true)
```

Comment: i used get_metadata and it is also not working
$meta_values = get_metadata('post', $post_id, 'salary', true);

Comment: Yes, replace the 'post' (1st param) with your custom post type name!

Comment: sorry i was wrong as i was new wordpress i completely misunderstood yr question. my post_type is 'post' only.

Comment: Then could you post more PHP code... Where you call get_metadata('post', $post_id, 'salary', true) and where you call it through "action(save_post,sftoproject)" (the exact code!).

Comment: OK, I could recommend to replace your code by get_metadata('post', $post_id, 'salary', true); and then try debugging the get_metadata() function located in wp-includes/meta.php. Here is the code for a quick look: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/meta.php#L255 ...it seems strange behaviour and probably you should first make sure you do not use a caching plugin!

Comment: i have tried get_metadata('post', $post_id, 'salary', true) also and it is  also not working.
when i echo its value its show blank

Comment: Try to debug the function if you can. I know it's a WP function and should not be changed, but you can debug it (check the params in the beginning of the function to check their values(!) and check is the function called(!); check if *each line of code* is doing something properly...) and then restore the original function... (or just more folks are viewing your question and include all questions+answers from the comments to your question)

Comment: I've read somewhere that if you call the function inside plugin class, it may not work! If this is the case with you, could you try to put it in the plugin file like: get_metadata('post', 999, 'salary', true) , where 999 is hardcoded just for the tests! (if not working, try to set the 4th param to FALSE as proposed by another member...)

Comment: yes, when i have hardcoded the value of $post_id, is it working correctly. I am able to get all value of wp_postmeta.
Provide solution for this

Comment: That's a progress! So according to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post , your code "$postdata = get_post($post_id);" may work by chance(opt.par)! Try inserting a line before that line and check the variable by: "echo $post_id; exit;". If there isn't ID, then this is the problem. According to http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post - "the data for the post is stored in $_POST, $_GET or the global $post_data, depending on how the post was edited", so you may try to use one of these variables instead. (Just a note: I never developed WP plugin so far...)

Comment: $post_id is showing correct id, $_POST,$_GET not working . Can you tell me how to use global $post_data for this?

Comment: I think you don't have anything in the $post_data if you don't have anything in the $_POST!! But what I didn't understand is how $post_id shows correct ID and get_metadata() doesn't return the value, but when you hardcode the $post_id param as INT - it works? Is the only change when the function works is replacing the "$post_id" with an integer? Or you also move the get_metadata() outside your function to work?